# pytorch Pretrained Resnet is not same accuracy Imagenet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, pre-trained-model

CPU : intel Zeon
GPU : NVIDIA RTX2080Ti
python : 3.6 
torch version : 1.4
torchvision version : 0.5.0

I Download ILSVRC2012(Imagenet Dataset) torrent, and do evaluation validation set.

choosed model is torchvision.datasets.Resnet50(pretrained=True) and i expected to validation top 1 accuracy over 60%.

I find corrects label of validation set in the below link https://github.com/fh295/semanticCNN/blob/master/imagenet_labels/ILSVRC2012_validation_ground_truth.txt

And cross verified with the link below.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/data/imagenet_2012_validation_synset_labels.txt

i made custom dataset for validation set, and evaluation.

But contrary to my expectation, the evaluation accuracy came out very low as if it had not been learned.
(accuracy is 0.1% ~ 0.05%)

this is my testing code and uploaded github https://github.com/pdh930105/pytorch_imagenet_test

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import PIL.Image as Image
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import os
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchvision
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((256, 256)),
                                transforms.CenterCrop((224, 224)),
                              transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

class val_imagenet_dataset(Dataset):   
    def __init__(self, root="../imagenet/", transform=None):
        self.transform = transform
        self.root = root
        self.data = []
        self.target = []
        f = open(self.root+"/ILSVRC2012_validation_ground_truth.txt")
        label_data = f.readlines()
        file_list = os.listdir(self.root)
        image_list = [image for image in file_list if image.endswith(".JPEG")]
        image_list.sort()
        for idx, label in enumerate(tqdm(label_data)):
            self.data.append(image_list[idx])
            self.target.append(int(label)-1) 

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path, target = self.data[idx], self.target[idx]

        with open(self.root+path, 'rb') as f:
            img = Image.open(f)
            sample = img.convert('RGB')


        if self.transform is not None:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample, target


def val_model(model, dataloader, device, criterion =None):
    since = time.time()
    acc = 0
    loss = 0
    data_size = dataloader.dataset.__len__()
    for inputs, labels in tqdm(dataloader):
        model.eval()
        model.to(device)
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        acc += torch.sum(preds==labels.data)

        if criterion is not None:
            _loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss +=_loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            print("local loss : {:4f}".format(loss))

    acc = acc.double()/data_size
    loss = loss / data_size

    print("Acc : {:4f}".format(acc))
    if criterion is not None:
        print("Loss : {:4f}".format(loss))

val_imagenet = val_imagenet_dataset(transform=transform)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_imagenet, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

resnet_50_origin = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

val_model(resnet_50_origin, val_dataloader, device=device)
```

It is my code but run accracy is 0.01%

Please let me know the problem of my code.